# Cannot see records in form bounded to table in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form and it's record source is a table. I created the form separately and added the control sources to the different fields in the form and also changed it's record source. I imported values from an excel sheet into the table and when I open the form, I do not see the tabe values being displayed in the form. Any idea what I should do to see the table records in the form?

Answer (score 1):

In form design mode, check the form's DataEntry property. It sounds like yours is set to Yes, which hides existing records and only allows new entries. Change it to No and you will see the existing records.
Another possibility is that a filter is active and no records match that filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a form wizard to generate a working form based on your table. Then once you can see the data being displayed in the form, customise as needed.